# Manipulating a Pre-existing Rigg

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, sculpting

I wanted to know if it's possible to take an pre-existing 3D rigged model, specifically this one... https://gumroad.com/l/JJuKG and have the model reworked to look more stylized, like this... https://www.artstation.com/artwork/LEme0 and have the rig expanded to give the model more cartoony exaggerations, squashing and screeching capabilities like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esYak0NuEP0?

Comment: hello, yes you can, you can make any change to the mesh, it will still be controlable by the armature the way it is currently. As for more cartoony expressions, it depends on how it is set right now, but you can make the changes you want later.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.